# Inflating an conductive balloon with charge

Tags: forces, electrostatics, home-experiment

Assume you have a deflated, thin film, conductive balloon. When left alone, the balloon would lay flat on a table. Now assume that the balloon has charge. With enough charge, would the electrostatic forces be enough to "inflate" the balloon so that it becomes more spherical?

To simplify the problem, consider also a conductive, thin film cylinder that would lay flat when left on a table. Would the flexible cylinder become more cylindrical with sufficient charge?

For some experimental backing, I recently took a rectangular piece of aluminum foil taped the short edges together to made a cylinder, connected one terminal of a power supply to the foil while the other terminal was left in the air, and applied 50V bias. Nothing happened to the foil for both the positive and the negative terminals. I thought I'd might see some kind of change in the shape of the foil as more charge was pushed into it, but perhaps I am missing something.

Looking forward to your feedback!

Answer (score 2):

The type of behavior you describe is quite possible, as long as the charged object is extremely light, and it's been done — in a commercial mass production form, even. There's a science toy called the “FunFlyStick” that is based on this principle.

The stick is a battery-powered handheld [Van de Graaff generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_de_Graaff_generator), and it comes with a set of very thin metalized mylar shapes, which can be charged and inflated by contact with the tip of the stick, then moved around in the air by repulsion from the stick or attraction from the rest of your body (since you're holding the stick and forming the negative electrode of the system). Some of the provided shapes are cylinders (hoops), though not spheres.

Here's [a video I found about the toy](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pRcpTffhLw4) that points out the components in a clear model and demonstrates it in use. Here's an image from 2:29 in the video (you can find lots more and better on the web):

[image]

If you're interested in home experiments with electrostatic forces, you might want to pick up one of these. It's not all that much more powerful a generator than the classic household electrostatic sources like rubbing hair, carpets, or (rubber) balloons, but it's capable of continuous operation.

Comment: This is great! Thank you! Do you know if the insulating mylar serves any other function besides being the substrate? I would imagine that this would work as well if the floating structure was completely conductive.

Comment: @thisbrainisourbrain I expect it mainly serves the purely mechanical purpose of making the structures sturdier (since extremely thin metal foils tear very easily). However, it is a dielectric, so it might have some effect on how much charge they readily hold, or something — I'm not equipped to do the math and tell you how much influence if any it has.

Answer (score 1):

It typically takes thousand of volts to exert enough force on a small object to counteract gravity.

[image]

Image from the [Library of Congress](https://www.loc.gov/everyday-mysteries/item/how-does-static-electricity-work/)

You can get thousands of volts by rubbing a balloon.

[image]

Image from [How Stuff Works](https://science.howstuffworks.com/why-do-balloons-stick-to-hair.htm)

But it takes more force to inflate a balloon than just to lift it. You have to stretch the rubber.

A high voltage is created by forcing extra electrons onto the balloon (or perhaps pulling them off), giving it a net charge. Electrons repel each other. It takes energy to overcome the repulsion. Voltage is the energy per electron.

If you try to force too many electrons on, they repel each other so hard that they leave in a spark. You would get sparks before the balloon inflated.